# Compile a software from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have a source code of a local tool which currently works on 32 bit VS 2008. Now I want to compile it on my system which is 64 bit and has VS2010. How can I achieve the compilation? Should I install the whole VS2008 or is it sufficient to install the 32-bit compiler and use 2010 IDE, and if so from where I can download the necessary tools to compile?

The same source code I want to upgrade i.e. compile it in 64 bit VS 2010. The tool has a dependency on Qt4.7.1 and Zlib 1.2.8. How can I achieve this up gradation?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you need 64-bit libraries of Qt and Zlib. Once you have all necessary 64-bit dll's required for your project, then you will need to link those libraries to linker in your project.

Compiling your tool with these libraries should be fine.

Comment: I found out the Zlib is compatible for 32 and 64 bit, am i right?

Comment: But they have not provided 64 and 32 bit downloads separately

Comment: Regarding to Qt, I would personally try the latest legacy version of Qt, which is 4.8.6. You can download them from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/). Remember to download the opensource version and compile yourself, as they don't have the precompiled version for visual studio 2010.

Comment: Sorry I meant Zlib.

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/madler/zlib) in order to compile with success. In contrib/vstudio/ you have solutions for each Visual Studio version.